# Summarise multiple columns at once in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, grouping, counting

I have some data (~70,000 rows) that is in a similar format to the below.

```
+-----------+-----+-----+----+-----------+
|    ID     |  A  |  B  | C  | Whatever  |
+-----------+-----+-----+----+-----------+
| 1banana   |  42 |   0 |  2 | Um        |
| fhqwhgads | 514 |   6 |  9 | Nevermind |
| 2banana   |  69 |  42 |  0 | NULL      |
| pears     |  18 |  96 |  2 | 8.8       |
| zubat2    |  96 |   2 | 14 | "NULL"    |
+-----------+-----+-----+----+-----------+
```

I want to make an output table that counts how many times each number occurs in any of the three columns, such as:

```
+--------+---------+---------+---------+-----+
| Number | A count | B count | C count | sum |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+-----+
|      0 |       0 |       1 |       1 |   2 |
|      2 |       0 |       1 |       2 |   3 |
|      6 |       0 |       1 |       0 |   1 |
|      9 |       0 |       0 |       1 |   1 |
|     14 |       0 |       0 |       1 |   1 |
|     18 |       1 |       0 |       0 |   1 |
|     42 |       1 |       1 |       0 |   2 |
|     69 |       1 |       0 |       0 |   1 |
|     96 |       1 |       1 |       0 |   2 |
|    514 |       1 |       0 |       0 |   1 |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+-----+
```

(In my real-world use, there would be at least 10 times as many rows in the input table than in the query result)

Whether or not the query returns a row of zeros for numbers that aren't anywhere in those 3 columns isn't that important, as is a lack of a distinct sum column (though my preferences are that it does have the sum column and numbers not in any column are excluded).

---

Currently, I am using the following query to get ungrouped data:

```
SELECT * #Number, COUNT(DISTINCT A), COUNT(DISTINCT B), COUNT(DISTINCT C)
FROM
    ( # Generate a list of numbers to try
    SELECT @ROW := @ROW + 1 AS `Number`
    FROM DataTable t
    join (SELECT @ROW := -9) t2
    LIMIT 777 # None of the numbers I am interested in should be greater than this
    ) AS NumberList
INNER JOIN DataTable ON
    Number = A
    OR Number = B
    OR Number = C
    #WHERE <filters on DataTable columns to speed things up>
#WHERE NUMBER = 10 # speed things up
#GROUP BY Number
```

The above query with the commented-out parts of the code left as they are returns a table similar to the data table, but sorted by which number of the entry it matches.  I would like to group together all rows starting with the same `Number`, and have the values in the "data" columns of the query result be the count of how many times the `Number` occured in the corresponding column of `DataTable`.

When I uncomment the grouping statements (and delete the `*` from the `SELECT` statement), I can get the count of how many rows each `Number` appeared in (useful for the `sum` column of the desired output).  However, it does not give me the actual totals of how many times the `Number` matched each data column: I just get three copies of the number of rows where `Number` was found.  **How do I get the groupings to be by each actual column instead of the total number of matching rows**?

---

Additionally, you may have noticed that I have some lines with comments regarding speeding things up.  This query is *slow*, so I added a couple filters so testing it runs faster.  I would very much like some way to make it run fast so that sending the results of the query from the complete set to a new table is not the only reasonable way to re-use this data, since I would like to have the ability to play around with the filters on `DataTable` for non-performance reasons.  **Is there a better way to structure the overall query so that it runs faster?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to unpivot using `union all` and then an aggregation:

```
select number, sum(a) as a, sum(b) as b, sum(c) as c, count(*) as `sum`
from ((select a as number, 1 as a, 0 as b, 0 as c from t
      ) union all
      (select b, 0 as a, 1 as b, 0 as c from t
      ) union all
      (select c, 0 as a, 0 as b, 1 as c from t
      )
     ) abc
group by number
order by number;
```

Comment: This works quite nicely!  It looks like I'll need to include whatever columns I forsee myself filtering from `t` three times, but I can use a `WHERE` filter right above the grouping and ordering. Is there a way to do this for a finite but unknown number of columns, or would a non-SQL DB (perhaps one that's 3-D) be a much better tool if I run into such a situation?